# Refactoring of long dict attributes line

Tags: python, refactoring

Code works fine but seems this line is ugly.

```
self.data["data"]["someComponent"]["items"][1]["content"]["items"].append(json.load(someVariable))
```

So my question is:
Is that suitable for code by python conventions? flake8, pylint, etc.. does not showing problems.
Maybe you have some fresh ideas for refactoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine for small programs or prototypes but it is bad for large and complex projects.

In case of long lines you can use `\` for move to the next line (but flake8 will give out warnings about the empty space before `[`):

```py
self.data \
    ["data"] \
    ["someComponent"] \
    ["items"] \
    [1] \
    ["content"] \
    ["items"].append(json.load(someVariable))
```

In serious projects, you should use other data structures. For example, the composition of objects of different classes, which forms the tree you need.

Create a class for each entity in your dictionary structure. For example, the `Data` class, which contains fields `someComponent` and, for example, `someOtherComponent`. Create class `Component`, which contains field `items` as list or make `Component` iterable (define method `__iter__()` and optionally method `__getitem__(index)`). And so on. And access to it's fields as:

```py
self.data.someComponent[1].content.append(myNewContentElement)
```

To get `myNewContentElement` from json you can create function which takes loaded JSON structure and returns `ContentElement` object for you.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My question means how to refactor that to do that less ugly and I'm looking for some best practices. 
Maybe you have some code example about 

**composition of objects of different classes** ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Have a nice day and mood!